# ObjectMapper not serialising new fields

Tags: swift, swift3, realm, objectmapper

I have an class:

```
class ChatMessage: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var fromId = ""
    dynamic var toId = ""
    dynamic var message = ""
    dynamic var fromName = ""
    dynamic var created: Int64 = 0



    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func configure(_ fromId:String,toId:String, message:String) {
        self.fromId=fromId
        self.toId=toId
        self.message=message
        self.created = Int64((NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0))

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        created  <- map["created"] //a: this was added later
        fromId <- map["fromId"]
        toId <- map["toId"]
        message <- map["message"]
        fromName  <- map["fromName"]

    }
}
```

I am using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to serialise the object to JSON and [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) to store it in the local database.
I had added the `created` field later to the mapping when the Realm db was already storing the `ChatMessage` object.

Now when I am instantiating the `ChatMessage` object and trying to convert it into JSON object using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). Following is the code:

```
  func sendChatMessage(_ chatMessage:ChatMessage, callback: @escaping DataSentCallback) -> Void {
        var chatMessageString:String!

        let realm = DBManager.sharedInstance.myDB

        try! realm?.write {
            chatMessageString = Mapper().toJSONString(chatMessage, prettyPrint: false)!

        }
...
}
```

Now when I print `chatMessage`, I get:

```
ChatMessage {
    fromId = 14;
    toId = 20;
    message = 2;
    fromName = ;
    created = 1477047392597;
}
```

And when I print `chatMessageString`, I get:

```
"{\"toId\":\"20\",\"message\":\"2\",\"fromName\":\"\",\"fromId\":\"14\"}"
```

How come does the `created` field not appear in the string?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the mapping of `Int64` type as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/130) on github.

By changing the mapping of `created` to the following form, everything worked fine:

```
created  <- (map["created"], TransformOf<Int64, NSNumber>(fromJSON: { $0?.int64Value }, toJSON: { $0.map { NSNumber(value: $0) } }))
```